# Recursive procedure with a counter?

Tags: loops, recursion, scheme, racket, counting

I am supposed to write a recursive algorithm to return the number of integers in an interval for which a predicate "`pred`" is true.

I managed to write the recursive part that moves from the lower bound to the upper bound, but I can't figure out how to implement a *counter* of some sort that increments by 1 each time that predicate is true for the integer, since my code is recursive (i.e. I keep calling the same method). If I create the counter inside the method, each time it's called, the counter will be initialized as 0.

What I wrote so far:

```
(define count-true
  (lambda (pred lower upper)
    (if (or (> lower upper) (= lower upper))
        (pred lower)
        (count-true pred (+ lower 1) upper))))
```

The original question:

> Write a recursive (not iterative) procedure, `(count-true pred lower upper)`, of type `(number->boolean),number,number->number`, that returns the number of integers in the range `lower..upper` (inclusive) for which predicate `pred` applied to that number is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In functional programming, you don't set local variable/counter. You use parameters or return values to pass (and name) data. In this case, you can use return value (if you don't want to change number of function parameters to add counter).

So every time when `pred` is `true`, you return what you received from recursive call incremented by `1`, or return what you received as is otherwise.

```lisp
(define count-true
  (lambda (pred? lower upper)
    (if (or (> lower upper) (= lower upper))
        0
        (if (pred? lower)
            (+ 1 (count-true pred? (+ lower 1) upper))
            (count-true pred? (+ lower 1) upper)))))
```

Comments:
I changed `pred` to `pred?` because it's a predicate, so it makes code more readable. You can also simplify this code to make call to `count-true` first and then use `if` to decide what to do with return value. And first `if` with `or` clause can also be simplified using `>=`. *"Little Schemer"* is great book if you want to learn recursion with lists, numbers etc.